# Access SQL SUM with subtraction

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am writing what I thought would be a relatively simple Access DB for a doctor client of mine who has a very small practice. I am having trouble with reporting a patient's balance.

I have 3 tables:

```
Patients (id, [First Name], [Last Name], {other cols})
Treatments (id, Fee, Patient_id, {other cols})
Payments (id, Amount, Patient_id, {other cols})
```

I want a query to simply show me the total fees for treatments, the total amount paid, and the current balance. I wrote the following...

```
Select 
 Patients.[Last Name],
 Patients.[First Name], 
 SUM(select SUM(Treatments.Fee) from Treatments Where Treatments.Patient=@PatientID)
AS CHARGES, 
 SUM(select SUM(PAYMENTS.AMOUNT) from PAYMENTS Where PAYMENTS.Patient=@PatientID)
AS PAYMENTS, 
SUM(
 (select SUM(Treatments.Fee) from Treatments Where Treatments.Patient=@PatientID)
- (select SUM(PAYMENTS.AMOUNT) from PAYMENTS Where PAYMENTS.Patient=@PatientID)
)
as Balance
FROM Patients,Treatments,PAYMENTS
WHERE Patients.ID = @PatientID
GROUP BY Patients.[Last Name],Patients.[First Name]
```

The Charges and Payments columns work fine, but the Balance I'm given is weird. The below is based on:

1. 5 treatment entries for this patient in the amounts, 50,25,35,45,125 (280).
2. 3 payment entries in the amounts, 15,60,25 (100).

I expect:
Charges = $280, Payments = $100, Balance = $180

But I get:
Charges = $280, Payments = $100, Balance = $2,700

Comment: why are you using subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using this FROM clause:

```
FROM Patients,Treatments,PAYMENTS
```

you're creating a Cartesian product.
Meaning your sum calculation for Balance will be multiplied by the number of records in each respective table (1 in Patients, 5 in Treatments, 3 in PAYMENTS):

- 15*total of fees- 15*total of payments = 15*280-15*100 = 4200-1500 =2700

You don't need Treatments and PAYMENTS in your FROM clause as you're doing your calculations in your sub query.
Use this statement instead:

```
Select 
 Patients.[Last Name],
 Patients.[First Name], 
 SUM(select SUM(Treatments.Fee) from Treatments Where Treatments.Patient=@PatientID)
AS CHARGES, 
 SUM(select SUM(PAYMENTS.AMOUNT) from PAYMENTS Where PAYMENTS.Patient=@PatientID)
AS PAYMENTS, 
SUM(
 (select SUM(Treatments.Fee) from Treatments Where Treatments.Patient=@PatientID)
- (select SUM(PAYMENTS.AMOUNT) from PAYMENTS Where PAYMENTS.Patient=@PatientID)
)
as Balance
FROM Patients
WHERE Patients.ID = @PatientID
GROUP BY Patients.[Last Name],Patients.[First Name]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
 Patients.[Last Name],
 Patients.[First Name], 
 SUM( treatments.Fee) 
AS CHARGES, 
 SUM(PAYMENTS.AMOUNT) 
AS PAYMENTS, 
SUM(Treatments.Fee) 
- SUM(PAYMENTS.AMOUNT) 
as Balance
FROM Patients a join Treatments b on a.id=b.patientid join PAYMENTS c on a.id=c.patientid
WHERE Patients.ID = @PatientID
GROUP BY Patients.[Last Name],Patients.[First Name]
```